# IE ignores my js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have validated this html. When I open it in a IE browser I cant see any alert. In other browsers I can. Any ideas why this is happening. HTML is valid according to http://validator.w3.org/check.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/loose.dtd">

<html>
   <head>
      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
      <title>hello</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">alert("hallo");</script>
      <div>Hello</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you turn off JavaScript in IE ?

Comment: It works perfectly well on IE9 here for me so it seems likely you have some local problem. Are you running it from a local file? IE prevents scripts running from a local file without permission (it puts a little message at the top or bottom of the main window asking for approval if I remember)

Comment: It works on IE 7 8 9 10 ..... u must be doing something wrong

Comment: @jcoder What's that!? Never heard before.

Comment: It was some setting. Did a reset settings http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737

Comment: If you put a script into a local html file on disk and open it in IE, it displays a warning before it is allowed to run. If you run it from a remote server it does not

Answer (score 5):

If you are opening the file locally in IE, you will a find confirmation message from IE saying

> "Allow blocked content"

Click on it and your code will run.